# In Android Studio I can't seem to run my app on two devices simultaneously

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, instant-run

I have two phones connected to my computer, via USB. I run my Android app from Android Studio on one of the phones. Then I want to run the same app, same version, on the other phone. But it doesn't start on the other phone, I don't get the popup to select a device. AS sais "gradle build finished", then nothing happens. I'd expect to see the device selection popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207055

I decided to switch off instant run so Android Studio has the behavior I know, and I like.

Comment: sorry for answering my own question, I though this is an ok way to share an answer from elsewhere.

Comment: It is perfectly fine :)